# 2-page Content slider for mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, slide

I'm trying to create a layout for mobile devices where I would show 2 screens (screenA and screenB ).
When a user would slide to a next page, screenA would disappear and screenB and screenC would be visible (after a sliding effect)

I've been looking into possibilities to do this with jQuery mobile, but no success yet however

Answer (score 0):

I know Sencha Touch has a carousel feature like you are describing.

If you want to stick with jQuery: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-carousel-sencha-style

Comment: cool.. and I thought I've seen all slide plugins.. This one is new to me and looks very nice .. +1 for the link

Comment: Well it doesn't necessarily have to be jQuery, as a matter of fact I've been looking into Sencha Touch, however the carousel there (and the one you suggested) are not exact the type of transition that I'm looking for.

Comment: @user485659 maybe you should describe it a little better. What kind of transition are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your quick replys; the idea is based on the official iPad twitter app: http://youtu.be/ehVbbOi-klY?t=29s
This app has been made as an iOS native app, but I'm looking for a way to simulate this behaviour through HTML5

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a Windows Phone 7(.5) application. Its Panorama control sounds similar or even better than what you want.